# How do I turn an brushless dc motor 1 cycle per second using pigpio and c++

Tags: pi-3b+, pwm, pigpio, c++

I am using an esc and a bldc and im trying to slowly spin my bldc

I can get my motor to spin with

```
gpioServo()
```

but when I use

```
gpioPWM()
```

It just continues to beep

when i use

```
gpioServo()
```

it spins way to fast

I want to control the speed of the motor down to revolution / second

I have found python examples maybe

I cant find a gpioPWM c example

If I understand correctly I want a frequence of 1hz and a duty cycle of 100%

Documentation below from pigpio.h from the function

```
gpioHardwarePWM()
```

which is what I'm using

---

```
. .
   gpio: see description
PWMfreq: 0 (off) or 1-125M (1-187.5M for the BCM2711)
PWMduty: 0 (off) to 1000000 (1M)(fully on)
. .
```

Here is my code

```
#include <pigpio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    gpioInitialise();
    cout << "Starting" << endl;

    time_sleep(2);

    gpioSetMode(13, 1);
    cout << "Setting mode!" << endl;
    time_sleep(2);

    gpioHardwarePWM(13, 1, 1000000);
    cout << "Starting" << endl;
    time_sleep(2);

    gpioTerminate();




    return  0;
}
```

A successful result would be to turn a  motor 1 revolution per second with the ability of that same motor to turn full throttle at much much higher speeds.

What am I missing?

Comment: A BLDC motor IS NOT a servo. If you want a servo you need to buy one. You can control speed (within limits) but it is open loop.

Comment: `I want a frequence of 1hz and a duty cycle of 100%` ... 100% duty cycle is DC ... there is no frequency

Comment: okay so maybe im misunderstanding something which would make sense to me because this is all new

how slow can a bldc go

Im trying to build an electric motorcycle from scratch

i can easily get a stepper motor but thats not my goal


if i need to buy a book i will but that is my goal

Comment: You need to add detail.  You can control a brushless motor (e.g. a hard drive platter motor) but is not easy and needs three control wires,  Perhaps you are using an ESC,

Comment: im sorry i assumed that was a given

I will update my description